# Typescript: differentiating HTMLElement's and SVGElement's addEventListener

Tags: javascript, typescript, addeventlistener

I am writing a class that can accept either an `HTMLElement` or a `SVGElement` and would like to bind and event with the `addEventListener` function that has the same signature on both types.
I have isolated a test case below.

My question: is it possible to get the right type for the `eventListener` `event` parameter without resorting to using `instanceof`?

```js
type HTMLorSVGElement = HTMLElement | SVGElement;

function test() {

  const htmlEl = document.querySelector('div');
  const svgEl = document.querySelector('svg');

  const randomEl: HTMLorSVGElement | null = Math.random() > 0.5 ? htmlEl : svgEl;

  function eventListener(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log(event.clientX);
  }

  /*
  This usage produces the folowing error

  Error:(12, 39) TS2345: Argument of type '(event: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
    Type '(event: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
    Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.
    Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 20 more.
  */
  randomEl?.addEventListener('click', eventListener);

  /*
   This doesn't produce an error
   */
  if (randomEl instanceof HTMLElement) {
    randomEl.addEventListener('click', eventListener);
  } else if (randomEl instanceof SVGElement) {
    randomEl.addEventListener('click', eventListener);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting the error here, because the line `randomEl?.addEventListener('click', eventListener);` works fine in TypeScript 3.7 as far as I can see.

Comment: [Here's some working code](https://codepen.io/Rich_N/pen/ZEOZoVa).  It fires the event and shows whether it was an HTMLElement or SVGElement that was used.

Comment: I'm running TS 4.0.5. Your Code Pen works, but copying your example to my project, and even a fresh project with TS 3.7 produces the same error. It would appear that setting `strict` to `false` in `tsconfig.json` allows for compilation, but that would not be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the TypeScript compiler is getting confused when we have the [strictFunctionTypes flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) set to true.  Setting strict to true also sets this flag.

As the error message says, the compiler is getting confused about whether it can assign your eventListener function (MouseEvent -> void) to a type of EventListener, in spite of being perfectly capable of handling the syntax in less complicated scenarios.

There's a simple workaround that makes the code compile and work:

```
randomEl?.addEventListener('click', eventListener as EventListener);
```

Alternatively we can turn the troublesome flag off with `"strictFunctionTypes": false` in tsconfig.

I've updated [my CodePen](https://codepen.io/Rich_N/pen/ZEOZoVa) so it works with strict set to true, although the CodePen site doesn't actually let you set the strict flag I think.  If you copy the code locally it should work.

There's an [open issue on the TypeScript github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28357) that's related to this (and where I got the answer!).

Comment: In the original code I extracted my test-case from the `EventListener` cast lead to losing the type of the event parameter (which I needed) but could also be solved with a second cast. It looks like this is the cleanest solution.